# What‘s the difference between てもらいたい and てくれたい?

Tags: grammar

For example:

> 彼に買ってもらいたい

and

> 彼が買ってくれたい

Do they both convey the same meaning ("I want him to buy it for me")?

Answer (score 5):

彼が買ってくれたい sounds incorrect.

You can say:

> 彼に買ってもらいたい。 "I want him to buy (something)(for me)."

or

> 彼に買ってほしい。 "I want him to buy (something)."

Comment: もらう+たい⇒もらいたい、あげる+たい⇒あげたい　はあるけど、くれる+たい⇒くれたい　はないんですね。

Comment: 単純に相手の行為だからでは・・？

Answer (score 5):

Both of the following:

> お父{とう}さんに教{おし}えてもらう
> お父{とう}さんが教{おし}えてくれる

translate into "father teaches me"; the difference is that in the former, the son/daughter is the subject of the verb, while in the latter, father is the subject. This summarizes the difference between もらう and くれる. The two following sentences are equivalent:

> （わたしが）お父{とう}さんに教{おし}えてもらう
> お父{とう}さんが（わたしに）教{おし}えてくれる

Because the first person cannot be the subject of くれる (for this meaning of the verb), the 連用形 + たい construction sounds unnatural for this verb and it is never used by a native speaker. `もらいたい` works because this verb lets you be its subject.